# AspectJ: add static initializer to class

Tags: java, initialization, aspectj

Some of my Java classes have static methods marked with a special annotation, `@Assert`, containing sanity checks.

I'd like to perform these checks before any code gets actually executed. The best would be to call these methods from `<clinit>`. How to get similar behavior using AspectJ, and without modifying initial code?

Answer (score 2):

AspectJ provides a `staticinitialization(TypePattern)` pointcut definition that will select existing static initializers and intercept them.  Doesn't appear to be able to add static initializers to classes that don't have them, however.

Comment: There don't need to be explicit `static` blocks, however, it can act as a class-load join point.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to John's answer; the `staticInitialization` pointcut doesn't require there to be any `static` blocks, in which case it acts as a simple class load join point.

That would be the time to call your methods annotated with `@Assert`.