# Difference in list of loaded classes using verbose:class and aspectj -staticinitialization()

Tags: jvm, classloader, aspectj, verbose

Im using `verbose:class` option to find classes loaded in jvm. As an alternative to this im trying to use aspectj class load join point  `after() : staticinitialization(*)`. But some classes are missing with second option especially agent classes. What is the difference between both?. Is it possible to use point cut as alternative to verbose?

Comment: The first option traces all **loaded** classes, while the second - all **initialized** classes. Not all loaded classes are initialized. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100002/class-loading-vs-class-initialization

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053802/aspectj-add-static-initializer-to-class . staticinitialization() acts as a simple class load join point.